# `Assuming` combined with mathematical notation of `Integrate`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions, notation

I am trying to write down the following expression

```
Integrate[Exp[-a/2/x]/x/(x + 1), {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]
```

using mathematical notation. I have tried

```
Assuming[b > 0 && a > 0, Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^b E^(-(a/(2 x)))/(x (x + 1)) \[DifferentialD]x]
```

and in picture

[image: screenshot of mathematical notation from Mathematica]

However, Mathematica returns *Syntax: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.*

Could you please give guidance what is wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The solution was in the examples section of `Integrate`. The syntax error is with the superscript `^` after `\[Integral]` in `Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^b`. `Ctrl+%` has to be used instead of `Ctrl+^`.

Correctly:

```
Assuming[b > 0 && a > 0, \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(b\)]\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(-\*FractionBox[\(a\), \(2 x\)]\)], \(x \((x + 1)\)\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)]
```

This looks long here but copying it back to the Mathematica editor results again in the nice picture posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error with `Subscript`

Try

```
Assuming[b > 0 && a > 0, Integrate[Exp[-a/2/x]/x/(x + 1), {x, 0, b}]]
(*-E^(a/2) ExpIntegralEi[-((a (1 + b))/(2 b))]*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, that is not my question. The first line works fine. I am trying to rewrite it using nice notation. I think that my first line of code `Integrate[Exp[-a/2/x]/x/(x + 1), {x, 0, b}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]` and the screenshot should be equivalent and the former evaluates fine but the latter does not evaluate. The `Subscript` line is just a copy-paste of the screenshot from the Mathematica editor; I did not enter that. What is wrong in the screenshot? Do I write the integral incorrectly?

Comment: According to Mathematica's manual on `Integrate`, `Subscript` should be used to enter $x_{min}$, the lower boundary of the integral, when using "nice notation" (my terminology).

Comment: @drumath Might be! I tried to evaluate your code line(cut&paste) and Mathematica  gives an error